# dynamoDBStreams getRecords() returning empty records when ShardIteratorType is set to LATEST

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-streams, aws-sdk-js

I was trying to retrieve last minute's changes in DynamoDB via dynamodb streams with AWS-SDK for nodeJS.
I thought of its implementation by using *ShardIteratorType* as "LATEST". Every time I call getRecords() with the Iterator that I got getShardIterator() it is returning empty records whereas changing *ShardIteratorType* to "TRIM_HORIZON" returns the objects in that Shard.

I am unable to understand this behaviour. If anyone can help me figure it out, it would be appreciated.

Here is the pseudo code for the implementation.

```
let getShardIterator = async (shardID) => {
    let params = {
        ShardId: shardID,
        ShardIteratorType: "LATEST", //using TRIM_HORIZON is working fine
        StreamArn: streamInfo.StreamArn
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamoStreams.getShardIterator(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err) // an error occurred
            else resolve(data);
        });
    })
}

let getDataFromIterator = async (params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamoStreams.getRecords(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err, err.stack); 
            else resolve(data);           
        });
    })
}

let shardIterObj = await getShardIterator(ShardId); 
let data = await getDataFromIterator(shardIterObj);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs, `LATEST` will return just after most recent record, this option normally is used if you are have `worker/thread` running in background, so that any subsequent events can be picked up.

> TRIM_HORIZON - Start reading **at** the last untrimmed record in the shard
>   in the system, which is the oldest data record in the shard.
>
> LATEST - Start reading just **after** the most recent record in the shard,
>   so that you always read the most recent data in the shard.